# Clean terminal output when starting

Tags: command-line, customization

Whenever I launch a terminal console via "**ctr + alt + t**" I get my terminal like in the photo.

I'm new in Linux and I probably tweak the wrong settings, but when I start terminal I want clean console.
[image]

Comment: You probably have a malformed `export` (or - less likely - `declare`) statement in your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: how can I navigate to that file so I can share what's inside

Comment: It's a *hidden file* (by virtue of the leading `.`) - to see it in a file browser you will need to Show Hidden Files (Ctrl+H) or you can display it in a terminal using `cat ~/.bashrc` or `less ~/.bashrc` etc.

Comment: I open terminal and enter command "nano ~/.bashrc" after that I realized  that I modified this file before, so I just removed my traces and now the terminal is clean.
If you want you can write your answer so I can marked it as working solution

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer - including what modifications you removed if you can remember them, it may help future readers with similar issues

Answer (score 0):

This kind of output by terminal refers that the `~/.bashrc` file is likely modified.
Every time you will open a new instance of terminal you will have some output.
To solve this we need to navigate to the file and one command is

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

After that you will be in editing mode of the file.
My personal problem was that I had some unclean code of some application paths that I do not use now, so I deleted and that solved the problem.